# Bootstrap Tabbed Panel: Tab Change Problem Because of Wrong HTML ID

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I created a tabbed-panel for my web site.

But when I clicked second, third and other options, I can't change the content, it is always the same.
Why do you think that is?
Whenever I try to change the active panel, it always shows the first one. I think I have written correctly 'a href='#1' ...' parts, but I need your help.

```
 <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-21 col-lg-12 col-x1-12"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#1' class="nav-link active" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#2' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#3' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Pecoa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#4' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Selamet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="panel-image">
                                <img src="./images/1.jpg" class="image-fluid">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel-text">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                        unknown
                        printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                        survived not
                        only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
                        essentially
                        unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                        containing Lorem
                        Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                        including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">5</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">6</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">1</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `1`, `2`, `3` as ID but In HTML 4, ID values must begin with a letter, which can then be followed only by letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons and periods.

Here it's working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-21 col-lg-12 col-x1-12"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#tab1' class="nav-link active" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#tab2' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#tab3' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Pecoa</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href='#tab4' class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle='tab'>Selamet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="panel-image">
                                <img src="./images/1.jpg" class="image-fluid">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel-text">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                        unknown
                        printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                        survived not
                        only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
                        essentially
                        unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                        containing Lorem
                        Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                        including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">5</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">6</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4">1</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```